# How can I detect panning and zooming by the user with d3 zoomBehavior?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, events

I am using d3.zoomBehavior to enable panning and zooming on a map. It works fine. I also wrote code to recenter the map on a focused item, which is also working. I wish to disable this "automatic recentering" if the user has manually zoomed or panned (checking if the map controls are "dirty" or not.)

How can I access the events for when a user manually moves the map?

I have tried accessing the drag, wheel, and zoom events:

```
d3.select("svg").call(this.zoomBehavior).on("wheel", () => {
  console.log("user has zoomed with wheel"); // never gets called
}).on("drag", () => {
  console.log("user has panned map"); // never gets called
}).on("zoom", () => {
  console.log("zoom event"); // gets called even when the map is autofocusing -- not what I need.
});
```

Which events on the selection can I tie into to determine when the user is manipulating the zoom and pan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your zoomed function, check to see if `d3.event.sourceEvent` is defined. A zoom triggered by `selection.call(zoom.transform,someZoomTransform)` has a sourceEvent of null. Also, `sourceEvent.type` can provide additional information on the type of event (eg: wheel, mousemove).

This is the approach used in Bostock's [brush and zoom example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172). Manually brushing triggers a programmatic update of the zoom and manually zooming triggers a programmatic update of the brush: the example needs to detect what is a manual vs programmatic zoom/brush to avoid an infinite loop.

Below a programmatic zoom is applied to the svg (covers the snippet preview window), but you can also pan/zoom. By checking to see if sourceEvent is null, we can see if a zoom was initiated by the user or programmatically:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 600)
  .attr("height", 500);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .on("zoom", function() {
      if(d3.event.sourceEvent) {
        console.log("not programmatic zoom");
      }
      else {
        console.log("programmatic zoom");
      }
      
  })

svg.call(zoom);
svg.call(zoom.transform,d3.zoomIdentity);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with this condition

```js
 const action = d3.event.type === "zoom" && d3.event?.sourceEvent?.type === "mousemove" ? "PAN": "ZOOM";
```